# breaking out of a loop at end of file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to break out of a loop when all lines are finished being read. I've tried using `String temp = scan.nextLine`, `if temp.equals("") break` but that's not breaking out of the loop at the right time.

I want it to read until the end of the file and then it exit the loop, except the `while scan.hasNextLine()` is still evaluating to true when the last values in the file have been read.

Code:

```
int line = 0;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("reading first line");
    //means we're reading the board coordinates
    if (line == 0) {
        System.out.println("first line");
        boardX = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("boardX: " + boardX);
        boardY = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("boardY: " + boardY);
    }
    //we're reading the non smokers positions and storing them in an array
    int nonSmokersPosX;
    int nonSmokersPosY;
    nonSmokersPosX = scan.nextInt();
    nonSmokersPosY = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("non smokers position: " + nonSmokersPosX + " " + nonSmokersPosY);
    pairedCoordinates.add(new Pair(nonSmokersPosX, nonSmokersPosY));
    line++;
}
```

Input:

```
9 8
0 1
5 6
3 2
```

Output:

```
reading first line
first line
boardX: 9
boardY: 8
non smokers position: 0 1
reading first line
non smokers position: 5 6
reading first line
non smokers position: 3 2
reading first line
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: This is the second question you've asked today about this.  Is this part of a university assignment?

Comment: Add line numbers (real ones) to your code and the full stack trace with the exception. The code you show may not be where the exception comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop that uses the `hasNext()` function. Like so:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {...}
```

Also, you can check if the text file you are reading from has no extra lines at the end. You can also try just  `.hasNext()`

Comment: Thanks for replies. I added a condition at the end of the loop `if !scan.hasNext{ break` and it now exits at the right place.

Comment: @magna_nz You don't have to do that. The problem is that you're not consuming the end of line (if you want to check whether there are more lines). Please see my answer. But the simplest and cleanest way to make your code work is to put `scan.hasNextInt()` in your `while` condition.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions. What do you want to check for in the `while` condition; whether there is at least one more number, or one more line?

1. One more number

Then check, whether there is at least one more number: `while (scan.hasNextInt()) {`

2. One more line

Then make sure that you fully read the current line first. The scanner must advance past the end of the current line before it can determine whether there are more lines.
So as the last statement within your `while` loop, put: `scan.nextLine();`

Either of these two solutions will make your code run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop already has the condition: `while (scan.hasNextLine())`. It means keep going until we have a next line and if we don't exit out from loop.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may want to clean up your code. Your printed steps are incorrect and is not following the logic of the program.

```
int line = 0;
while (scan.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println("reading first line");
        //means we're reading the board coordinates
        if (line == 0){
            System.out.println("first line");
            boardX = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("boardX: "+boardX);
            boardY = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("boardY: "+boardY);
        } else {
        //we're reading the non smokers positions and storing them in an array
        int nonSmokersPosX;
        int nonSmokersPosY;
        nonSmokersPosX = scan.nextInt(); // <-- This is where your code was previously failing.
        nonSmokersPosY = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("non smokers position: "+nonSmokersPosX+" "+nonSmokersPosY);
        pairedCoordinates.add(new Pair(nonSmokersPosX, nonSmokersPosY));
   }
        line++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You tell us your input is:

```
9 8
0 1
5 6
3 2
```

I ask, where is your EOF?  When I used to grade assignments like these what made all the difference was if your last line of data ended in an EOF or another new line.

How to tell?  Open your input file and run the blinking cursor (some call it a caret) to the end.  Does it stop just to the right of the 2 or below the 3?

Once you KNOW about this it's not hard to program around, but it can be maddening to debug when you don't.  Hope it helps.